# How to loop through all the sheets in a workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to collect all the data of all the sheets in my workbook based on the due dates in every worksheet and sum all the data of from all the sheets and paste into one email.

My code works for one selected sheet.

If I select all the sheets it takes the data of one sheet and copies the same thing by the number of sheets selected.

```vb
Sub Followup()

Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application
Dim Source As String
Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application
Dim EmailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Set EmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim DateDueCol As Range
Dim DateDue As Range
Dim NotificationMsg As String
Set DateDueCol = Range("R2:R100")

For Each ws In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets

    For Each DateDue In DateDueCol
        If DateDue <> "" And Date >= DateDue + Range("AC1") Then
            NotificationMsg = NotificationMsg & "<br>" & DateDue.Offset(0, -16) & " " & DateDue.Offset(0, -13) & " " & "CL#- " & DateDue.Offset(0, -11) & " " & "DOS- " & DateDue.Offset(0, -10)
        End If
    Next DateDue

Next ws

EmailItem.To = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx "

EmailItem.Subject = "CLAIMS CROSSED THE FOLLOW-UP DUE DATE"

EmailItem.HTMLBody = "Hi," & "<br>" & "<br>" & "The following claims 
need chasing today: " & "<br>" & NotificationMsg & _
  "<br>" & "<br>" & _
  "Regards," & "<br>" & _
  "<br>" & "xxxxxxxxxx" & _
  "<br>" & " "

EmailItem.Display

End Sub
```

Comment: We need to see you code to answer this

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on the line

```
For Each ws In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
```

That's why it works only on the selected sheet. You should write something like:

```
For Each ws In ThiswWorkbook.Worksheets
```

That way you would loop through all of the sheets.

Comment: I also tried that but same thing.  Example - I want the code to generate all the due-data for sheet1 (here in my code is Notificationmsg) and than go to sheet2. It does that up to here no problem before the email code. If I give a msgbox it works fine. But the main problem is when it paste the notificationmsg in the emailbody. For example i have 3 sheets- when comes to paste the notificationmsg for each individual sheets - it just copy paste the same thing 3 times in the email body.

Comment: * it take the notificationmsg for sheet1 and just copy paste it 3 times in the email body.